# LightXML.jl: Insert doctype

Tags: xml, doctype, julia

How can I insert a doctype element in a XML document, using LightXML in julia? Following the example from https://github.com/JuliaLang/LightXML.jl, I would like to create:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc>
<States>
</States>
```

Without the doctype, the document can be easily created with

```
xdoc = XMLDocument()
xroot = create_root(xdoc, "States")
```

However, I couldn't find a way to insert the doctype.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question, but I think if you file an issue on the package someone may be able to either point you in the right direction and document it better, or add the feature - either way, good outcome.

Comment: I now opened an issue for the package: https://github.com/JuliaLang/LightXML.jl/issues/21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with LightXML.

[The word "doctype" does not appear in the entire codebase](https://github.com/JuliaLang/LightXML.jl/search?q=doctype), which means you are out of luck with this package.

Answer (score 1):

[EzXML.jl](https://github.com/bicycle1885/EzXML.jl) can do that:

```
julia> using EzXML

julia> doc = XMLDocument()
EzXML.Document(EzXML.Node(<DOCUMENT_NODE@0x00007fd7348432c0>))

julia> setroot!(doc, ElementNode("States"))
EzXML.Node(<ELEMENT_NODE@0x00007fd734a9ddb0>)

julia> setdtd!(doc, DTDNode("doc"))
EzXML.Node(<DTD_NODE@0x00007fd734a7b950>)

julia> print(doc)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc>
<States/>
```